# Saving an object/struct to database as Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization

I am using rails and I would like to store a struct in my db. I figured the best way to do this would be to serialize it as json or yaml and then retrieve it, but I am running into some issues. Mostly, when I I look at the db the info looks like it's stored fine, but when I try to retrieve it, all of the info is escaped and encoded strangely.

Can someone point me in the right direction in terms of learning about json encoding and storing in a db? Also good ways of retrieving it and running the json?

Thanks so much! Let me know if you would like some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing JSON.parse(@object.struct_column) while reading data back? For example:

```
@my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id]))
config     = JSON.parse(@my_object.struct_column)
```

Also, [these](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-activerecord-serialize-method.html) [two](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) are good reads in that connection.

Comment: Those articles were definitely helpful, the bigger issue I had though was once the json was stored in the db, it was difficult to pull it out and send it over ajax without strange escaping issues happening. I guess this happens because of way rails pulls string with quotation marks and what not. Any ideas or articles you know of on how to deal with that?